# Does Snowflake have an equivalent to the TeraData nPath?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

In Teradata I can get rid of noise rows and just pick the first and last dates of a series of rows with nPath. I don't see a Snowflake function with the same name, but I'm thinking there might be one with a different name.

In Teradata if I code:

```
create VOLATILE TABLE tEmpLocationsClean as
    (
    SELECT * FROM NPath
        (ON tEmpLocations
             PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID, LOCATION_CODE
             ORDER BY LOCATION_START_DATE
             USING
               MODE (NonOverlapping)
               Symbols (LOCATION_START_DATE-1 > lag(LOCATION_END_DATE, 1, date '0001-01-01') AS newgrp, -- starting row of a group of overlapping rows
                        LOCATION_START_DATE-1 <= lag(LOCATION_END_DATE, 1, ) as x)                      -- overlapping row
               Pattern ('newgrp.x*')                                                  -- start plus overlapping rows
               RESULT(First (  EMPLOYEE_ID OF newgrp) AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
                        First (  EMPLOYEE_FULL_NAME OF newgrp) AS EMPLOYEE_FULL_NAME,
                        First (  LOCATION_CODE OF newgrp) AS LOCATION_CODE,    
                        First (  LOCATION_DESCRIPTION OF newgrp) AS LOCATION_DESCRIPTION,   
                        -- grouping column(s)
                      first (LOCATION_START_DATE OF ANY(newgrp, x)) AS LOCATION_START_DATE,             -- start date of group 
                      last  (LOCATION_END_DATE   OF ANY(newgrp, x)) AS LOCATION_END_DATE              -- end date of group                  
                     )
            )
    )
    With data
    on commit preserve rows;
```

I can't seem to find a similar technique in Snowflake and expected that I would.

Answer (score 0):

`first_value` and `last_value` are likely what you're looking for from Snowflake.  I'm going to make assumptions on your example, so this may not be exactly what you're looking for, but the syntax would be something like:

```
select
    first_value(DATE) over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID, LOCATION_CODE order by DATE nulls last) as LOCATION_START_DATE,
    last_value(DATE) over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID, LOCATION_CODE order by DATE) as LOCATION_END_DATE
from
    TABLEA;
```

Comment: Excellent thank you Mike.  It seems if I use that withing a MATCH_RECOGNIZE I am getting the results I was looking for.

Comment: @Patrick Glad I could help.  Please feel free to mark this response as your accepted answer, if it's working for you.